# Regarding couchbase lite and sync gateway

Tags: couchbase-lite

I am able to connect sync `gateway` to `couchbase server`. I have a consideration like `couchbase lite` is used as a local `database` or standalone `database` for windows application.

**Clarification Required:**

1. How the `couchbase lite` (local database from application) is connected with sync gateway? is it done by API provided by Couchbase lite?
2. Does any one having simple java code which will help to getting the things like how to connect with db and how to handle database by using java code?

Comment: improved clarity in question

Answer (score 0):

```
private URL createSyncURL(boolean isEncrypted){
    URL syncURL = null;
    String host = "https://10.0.2.2";  //sync gateway ip
    String port = "4984";              //sync gateway port
    String dbName = "couchbaseevents";
    try {
        syncURL = new URL(host + ":" + port + "/" + dbName);
    } catch (MalformedURLException me) {
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
    return syncURL;
}

private void startReplications() throws CouchbaseLiteException {
    Replication pull = this.getDatabaseInstance().createPullReplication(this.createSyncURL(false));
    Replication push = this.getDatabaseInstance().createPushReplication(this.createSyncURL(false));
    pull.setContinuous(true);
    push.setContinuous(true);
    pull.start();
    push.start();
}
```

When you call the startReplications method it will internally call createSyncURL which connects couchbase lite db to sync gateway

Comment: one more silly question....i am not clear about couchbase lite...is it just a api or there is a different application of couchbase lite? means what is it exactly?? @Legendary_Hunter

Comment: Couchbase lite is a database inside your mobile just like sql lite

Comment: I am trying  to create  desktop application using couchbase lite...so at client side how should i embed couchbaselite to my application?

Comment: For desktop use couchbase server, for mobile use couchbase lite. you can exchange data between cb server and cb lite using bucket shadowing

Comment: Yes, for a desktop app you can use Couchbase Lite.  In that case, you are embedding libraries, just like in a mobile app.

Comment: is there any method by which i can detect directly that couchbase lite db is changed or not..

Comment: @Hod   i need help , i have replicated data in couchbase server using pull push , but many metadata fils are added into it , is there any option to add  only data added by code (not unused metadata)

Comment: @Legendary_Hunter need help for above issue

Comment: @Shriram added comment to your other SO post.  Can you respond there and explain use case?  CBL needs the metadata to sync, so if you get rid of it, you won't be able to sync anymore.

Comment: @Shriram CBL needs metadata to sync and keep track of documents. I guess for now it wont be able to avoid metadata. You can still ask the same question in CouchBase forums

Comment: i got the way to avoid the metadata , we  can just shadow the synced bucket, and it'll shadow only the document data (without meta) :)

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase Lite is an embedded database.  It supports many platforms, both mobile and desktop.

Couchbase Lite is a complete, fully functional database that can be used stand-alone.  This means your app must include Couchbase Lite library code.

When working with Sync Gateway, Couchbase Lite performs replications using REST calls behind the scenes.  You can actually use Sync Gateway directly yourself using REST calls.

There are code samples on the [Couchbase Mobile developer portal](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile).  Here's a snippet in Java (Note: On Android, use an AndroidContext instead of a JavaContext):

```
// Get the database (and create it if it doesn’t exist).
Manager manager = new Manager(new JavaContext(), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
Database database = manager.getDatabase("mydb");

// Create a new document (i.e. a record) in the database.
Document document = database.createDocument();
Map properties = new HashMap();
properties.put("firstName", "John");
document.putProperties(properties);

// Update a document.
document.update(new Document.DocumentUpdater() {
    @Override
    public boolean update(UnsavedRevision newRevision) {
        Map properties = newRevision.getUserProperties();
        properties.put("firstName", "Johnny");
        newRevision.setUserProperties(properties);
        return true;
    }
});

// Delete a document.
document.delete();

// Create replicators to push & pull changes to & from the cloud.
URL url = new URL("https://www.my.com/mydb/");
Replication push = database.createPushReplication(url);
Replication pull = database.createPullReplication(url);
push.setContinuous(true);
pull.setContinuous(true);

// Add authentication.
Authenticator authenticator = AuthenticatorFactory.createBasicAuthenticator(name, password);
push.setAuthenticator(authenticator);
pull.setAuthenticator(authenticator);

// Listen to database change events (there are also change
// events for documents, replications, and queries).
database.addChangeListener(this);

// Start replicators
push.start();
pull.start();
```

Comment: database.addChangeListener(this);  is not allowing this object, it asks for the ChangeListner ref  which is having one abstract method as void changed(ChangeEvent)

Comment: @Shriram in the sample, the class encapsulating the code declares itself as implementing the ChangeListener interface.  Then you fill in the required method.